# Dynamic compile-time base class

Tags: c++

**Please note this is a question about template syntax only -- not general c++ object oriented, polymorphism design. This example is a fabrication for that purpose**

Say I have a base class:

```
class A: public B
{
...
};
```

I use it...

```
A a;
a.DoSomething();
```

What If I wanted to do something like this, to be able have a compile-time derivation of A, not only from B but from other classes. So that I can use it like this:

```
A<B> a;                // like class A : public B
a.doSomething();

A<C> ac;              // like class A : public C
ac.DoSomething();
```

Can I do something like this?

```
template <typename BASECLASS>
class A : public BASECLASS
{
...
};
```

Let's assume my constructor had a parameter and I knew that whatever template I use for hte base class had the same signature. If so, this is the *.h file, what do you do with the *.cpp file? Is that legal for initializing the constructor?

```
A::A(int param) : BASECLASS(param)
{

}
```

**Please note this is a question about template syntax only -- not general c++ object oriented, polymorphism design.**

Comment: Yes, that is possible, but in my experience this is looking for polymorphism when composition is what is really needed...

Comment: as noted below, this is a question about template syntax only. The example is fabricated.

Comment: (this is static polymophism, btw)

Comment: technically, yes. you are correct.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557141/static-polymorphism-definition-and-implementation (more info)

Comment: @luk32, not quite.  CRTP is different and its use to get at derived methods from within the base class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the syntax correct in your example.  Here is a minimal compilable example.

```
template <class Base>
class A : public Base {

};

class B {
public:
  void doSomething() {}
};
class C {
public:
  void doSomething() {}
};

int main() {
  A<B> a;                // like class A : public B
  a.doSomething();

  A<C> ac;              // like class A : public C
  ac.doSomething(); 
}
```

Comment: So this must defined in a single file? no *.h/*.cpp separation?

Comment: Class B and class C's function defintions can be in the .cpp, but they need to be declared before A.

Comment: Like all templates, the entire function body has to be available at compile time, rather than link time.  So A needs to be in headers only.  But B and C can be done normally.

Comment: what if A had a constructor that required a parameter? and classes B and C also had similar constructors? can you make the A constructor in a separate *.cpp file?

Comment: @MadScienceDreams, correct me if I'm wrong, but AFAIK B and C don't need to be declared before A?  The example given compiles just fine.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity Sorry, before the instantiation of A<Foo> is the right way to say it, my bad :-P

Answer (score 0):

Actually, with C++11, this became even more easy:

```
template <typename T>
class A: public T {
public:
    template <typename... Args>
    explicit A(Args&&... args): T(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}

};
```

This use of variadic template arguments (`typename...`) combined with reference collapsing (`&&` in a template deduces to the best reference match possible) and `std::forward` allows for *perfect forwarding*; as if the "layer" of A's constructor was transparent.

Comment: While 100% correct and awesome, this might be a tad advanced for someone who's uncertain how to work with template types at all.

Comment: `using T::T;` might be simpler for a neophyte, and has similar effect.