# Static polymorphism

Tags: static, polymorphism

Static polymorphism is in fact involves binding of functions based on number or type of arguments and is also known as parametric polymorphism.

It seems that static polymorphism is not really polymorphism, because the interface looks different and is like calling a function with different types or number of parameters.

can somebody tell me that static polymorphism is really a polymorphism or not?

please give some reasons if possible.

Answer (score 0):

It's in the name.. poly-morphic, i.e. handling many-shaped arguments.

There is no real difference between

```
f(A) :- ...
f(B) :- ...
```

and

```
class A:
    f() :- ...
class B():
    f() :- ...
```

Comment: I know what is polymorphism but I want to know that what is the difference between dynamic and static polymorphism and I also want to know that is static polymorphism is really a polymorphism or not?

Comment: Read the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4557141/static-polymorphism-definition-and-implementation